# Why does Darktable show D5300 RAW (.NEF) in pink in darkroom?

Tags: raw, troubleshooting, linux, darktable, nikon-d5300

I just installed Darktable, in lighttable mode my raw files are shown proper but in darkroom it shows pinkish.

[image]

e.g. File

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33211952/dsc_0013.nef 
Screenshot https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33211952/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-06%2019%3A56%3A09.png

Comment: What camera model?

Comment: I notice that Base Curve is turned on, which means your copy is automatically applying it for new pictures or you've selected one that applies the offsets to the red and blue channels shown in the histogram.

Comment: Even though if I off Base Curve there is no effect.

Comment: @mattdm Nikon D5300

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: @sebix sure https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33211952/dsc_0013.nef and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33211952/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-06%2019%3A56%3A09.png

Comment: @Mah no I have not check with dcraw or ufraw. But i have checked with shotwell and in that case its shows properly.

Comment: @Mah — actually, Darktable uses [RawSpeed](http://rawstudio.org/blog/?p=800) (which doesn't use dcraw) and [LibRaw](http://www.libraw.org/) (which does). I don't think it uses ufraw at all.

Comment: @mattdm My mistake. That's what it seems to use in order to process my Sony ARW files. I made an unjustified generalization.

Comment: @Mah ufraw is used by GIMP, maybe you had that in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have a D5300, the answer is clear — Darktable just added support for that camera in [version 1.4.2](http://www.darktable.org/2014/04/released-darktable-1-4-2/), at which point it was listed as "experimental". [Darktable 1.6](http://www.darktable.org/2014/12/released-darktable-1-6/) was released a month ago (December 2014), so upgrading to that should solve your issue.

If it *doesn't*, I'd add your feedback (and a sample file?) to this issue tracker request: [Feature #9764: Support Nikon D5300 NEFs](http://darktable.org/redmine/issues/9764) — it may be that there are still some kinks in that experimental support to work out.